# run animation only if not already running jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s [Bounce Effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/) on a click event like this

```
$("#myelm").click(function(){
    $(".wlbutton").children("span.new").effect( "bounce", "slow");
});
```

I would want to run the effect only if it's not already running. So if you click twice fast it will only act on the first click. How can I achieve this?

I've tried to clear the queue with jQuery's .stop() without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.not` to filter it:

```
$('#myelm').click(function(){
   $('.wlbutton').children('span.new').not(':animated').effect('bounce', 'slow');
});
```

However I would use `.is` function to check instead of a filter because of code readability

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:animated` selector to check whether the particular element is `animating` or not. If it is currently getting animated, Just let that `click` event ignored.

Try,

```
$("#myelm").click(function(){
    var xEle = $(".wlbutton").children("span.new");
    if(xEle.is(':animated')) { return; }
    xEle.effect( "bounce", "slow");
});
```

The another way would be using `.stop()`.

```
$("#myelm").click(function(){
    $(".wlbutton").children("span.new").stop().effect( "bounce", "slow");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8EWAN/3/)

Comment: I've tried both those methods but I't wont work. Here's a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8EWAN/1/

Comment: @daker I just provided a demo, Please visit.